# May I say that reading web pages "faces some ... readability issues"?

Tags: word-usage

I wrote this sentence

> The rapid growth of World Wide Web has been tremendous in recent years. With the large amount of information on the Internet, web pages have turned to the main source of information. However, **reading web pages faces some obstacles and readability issues**.

Is using "face issue" for "reading" and adding "readability" as adjective, a natural combination?

Comment: *Reading...faces ...some...readability issues*  is an issue.  "Turned to" should read "become".  Simpler to say "Web pages have some readability issues".  Writing faces readability issues, not reading.

Comment: Did you mean "turned *into*"? Or you could use *become*; "web pages have *become* the main source of information"

Comment: I think "turn out to be the ...:")

Comment: Also, I would not put "obstacles and readability" together if readability is an obstacle. Perhaps "However, reading web pages faces some obstacles *such as* readability issues (and XXX)."

Comment: I think it would be slightly more natural to say that reading web pages *has* some issues, but *faces* or *encounters* some obstacles. My reasoning is that *obstacles* and *issues* are not quite parallel. Metaphorically, "obstacles" are outside of the act of reading but prevent the act from occurring, but "issues" are a part of the act of reading. A *reader* may face an issue or an obstacle, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of issues is correct however I would definitely make some changes:

> The rapid growth of **the** World Wide Web has been tremendous in recent years. With the large amount of information on the Internet, web pages have **become** the main source of information. However, **in** reading web pages **,** **there are** some obstacles and readability issues.

That is probably the closest fix to what you wrote.